# unique email address on update form in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net page which has a list of users. I want to edit these users. Each user has a unique email address. On update page, on click of Save button, I am checking if a user exists against the email address typed in email address field of the form. If no, then I want to show error. Also, I want to make sure that user doesn't enter email address on update form which is used by some other user. How can I make sure that an email address which user typed is not used by some other user?

Here is the code I have used so far:

```
 UserAuthentication ua1 = null;
 ua1 = UserAuthenticationManager.GetUserByEmail(objUserProfile.Email);

 if (ua1 != null)
 {
   //update
 }
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean you need a validation attribute for that? [RemoteValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg508808%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) would work for you.

But if you want to do just one request for both operations then you will have to settle with only server validation for this unique check. You can write a [custom validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation.aspx) (plenty of examples on the net) or you can cheat and do something like

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   if (UserAuthenticationManager.IsUniqueByEmail(model.Id, model.Email))
   {
      // do update
   }
   else
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user email already exists");
   }
}
```

Make sure that you have a validation summary in your view though.

Sql behind IsUniqueEmail to spot duplicates by email should look like

```
select *
from Users
where Id <> @Id and Email like @email
```

Comment: What will UserAuthenticationManager.IsUniqueByEmail(model.Email) do ? How can i make sure that email address is unique in the table and is only connected currently selected user.

Comment: Since we talk about update, you should also keep the user ID like Html.HiddenFor(user => user.Id) then the check method IsUniqueByEmail could get both Id and email which I think are suffice to determine that.

Comment: What namespace contains UserAuthenticationManager.IsUniqueByEmail?

Answer (score 1):

Use action as `JsonAction` and check in action and return status into this.

Comment: I need to do it all on one button click, checking the email address duplication as well as update. I am using asp.net MVC

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var _user = Membership.GetUserNameByEmail(_emailid);

if(_user != null)
{
    //email already exits
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Email id already exists.");
}
else
{
   //new email address
}
```

Comment: @Anit: This will failt If user doesnt change email address. user will get error If he doesnt want to change email and want to change other fields only and hit update button